# FluentNHibernate Overrides: UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf non-generic version

Tags: c#, generics, fluent-nhibernate, overriding, automapping

I have a repository class that inherits from a generic implementation:

```
public namespace RepositoryImplementation {
    public class PersonRepository : Web.Generics.GenericNHibernateRepository<Person>
}
```

The generic repository implementation uses Fluent NHibernate conventions. They're working fine. One of those conventions is that all properties are not nullable.

Now I need to define that specific properties may be nullable outside the conventions. Fluent NHibernate has an interesting override mechanism:

```
public namespace RepositoryImplementation {
    public class PersonMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Person> {
        public void Override(FluentNHibernate.Automapping.AutoMapping<Funcionario> mapping)
        {
            mapping.Map(x => x.PhoneNumber).Nullable();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to register the override class into Fluent NHibernate. I have the following code in the `Web.Generics.GenericNHibernateRepository` generic class:

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Person>()
  .Where(type => type.Namespace == "Entities")
  .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<PersonMappingOverride>();
```

The problem is: `UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf` is a generic method, and I can't do something like that:

```
.UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<PersonMappingOverride>();
```

Because that would cause a circular reference. I don't want the generic repository to know the either repository or the mapping override class, because they vary from project to project.

I see another solution: in the GenericNHibernateRepository class I can do this.GetType() and get the repository implementation type (e.g.: PersonRepository). However I can't call `UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf()` passing a type.

Is there another way to configure overrides in FluentNHibernate? If not, how could I call `UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<T>` without making the generic repository depend upon the repository implementation or the mapping override class?

(Source: http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Overrides)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way I do it (source over on http://github.com/ToJans/MVCExtensions/blob/master/src/MvcExtensions/Services/Impl/FluentNHibernate/Database.cs )

```
    am1.GetType()
   .GetMethod("UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf")
   .MakeGenericMethod(mappings.GetType())
   .Invoke(am1,null);
```